# redundant rows are then in answer

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT item_id,
       CREDITBAL= (SELECT Sum(quantity)
                   FROM   axi_quantity_registers
                   WHERE  from_where != 'OPENING'
                          AND transaction_type = 'C'),
       OPENBAL = (SELECT Sum(quantity)
                  FROM   axi_quantity_registers
                  WHERE  from_where = 'OPENING'),
       DEBITBAL = (SELECT Sum(quantity)
                   FROM   axi_quantity_registers
                   WHERE  transaction_type = 'D')
FROM   axi_quantity_registers
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get better answers for your questions

Comment: Do you really expect someone to help/answer you with that question. Explain what are you trying to achieve..Add sample data and expected result

Comment: item_id   CREDITBAL   OPENBAL  DEBITBAL  1    200 500 250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want a `GROUP BY` with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT item_id,
       sum(case when from_where != 'OPENING' AND transaction_type = 'C' then quantity end) as CREDITBAL,
       sum(case when from_where = 'OPENING' then quantity end) as OPENBAL,
       sum(case when transaction_type = 'D' then quantity end) as DEBITBAL
FROM   axi_quantity_registers 
group by item_id
```